# Using rotateY vs matrix3d in css3

Tags: css, matrix, transform

Heyho. I just came up with a tricky question.
I did something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LspdF/1/

As you cann see there are more than 4 sites. Thats why I did the following:
Whenevery the pic-numer is greater than the last pic-number I turn the cube left, otherwise rigt. Thats why it can happen, that the css is somewhat like this:
`transform: rotateY(450deg)`

Since a circle only has 360 deg it turns and turns but always in the right direction.

Now I wanted to add a nice effect. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/p8a2t/

For this effect I need the 14th value of the 3d matrix created by the browser (z-value of translation). Since this value is poorly not the same as `translateZ()`, I have to use the `matrix3d()`-attribute.

Thats why I calculate the `rotateY` myself. But as you know the `sin` and `cos` are periodic and wont work with my 450deg. They reset the cube to 90deg which makes the cube spin back very fast.

My Question: How to denie that? Is there any possibility to change the matrix for spinning more than 360deg?

PS: The effect is realized using transition. There may be code in the fiddles which isnt used since I had to create both examples at once.

PPS: Sometimes the calculation has fatal numeric errors (near zero but not rly zero). I tried to avoid that using `toFixed` but for some reason that wont work sometimes. Same with `Math.round`. Note that you can break the second example clicking many links while the animation is still not done. But thats no point here :)

Any help is appreciated!